# How do I choose a nozzle for PA12+CF for Kobra Max?

Tags: filament, nozzle, anycubic-kobra-max

I am sorry if I sound too newbie, but to me, it seems like an unsolvable riddle:

I have not yet used any other nozzle than the one that comes with my printer.

I would now like to print Fiberlogy Nylon PA12+CF15 black, 1.75 mm on a Kobra Max, and in one YouTube video, somebody says that 260 °C were not hot enough for PA12+CF yet.

So I guess I have to buy a new nozzle as somebody in a review video said that the Kobra Max nozzle diffuses at over 260 °C.

How do I find a fitting nozzle and what do I need to pay attention to?

I have googled "Kobra Max full metal hot end" and found this [Hotend for Anycubic Kobra Max](https://www.anycubic.com/products/hotend-for-kobra-max) on Anycubic's site, but it is being sent from China and takes 2-3 weeks. I would very much like to find one that is being delivered faster, but I don't know what else to search for.